# Problem reading and writing from MS sql server in R studio Session using odbc

Tags: r, sql-server, linux, odbc

I am unable to read or write R objects to Microsoft SQL 2017 database.
This may seem like a question that is already answered. So, some context:
I have hosted a Linux data science VM on Azure. 
SQL 2017 Express version is installed on this machine. (So there is no separate server for sql)
I am using Rstudio server hosted on this machine.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)  
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "libtdsodbc.so", Server = "localhost", 
                 Database = "CBD", UID = "SA", PWD = "mypwd", 
                 Port = 1433)

data <- dbWriteTable(con, "iris2", iris, overwrite = TRUE)


Error: <SQL> 'CREATE TABLE "iris2" (
  "Sepal.Length" FLOAT,
  "Sepal.Width" FLOAT,
  "Petal.Length" FLOAT,
  "Petal.Width" FLOAT,
  "Species" varchar(255)
)
'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'iris2'. 




#Suggestes solutions from GIT
tbl <- dbId(con, "iris2")
tbl1 <- Id(table = "iris2")
data <- dbWriteTable(con, tbl, iris, overwrite = TRUE) # not working same error
data <- dbWriteTable(con, tbl1, iris, overwrite = TRUE) # not working same error
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding flag Trusted_Connection="True" to the dbConnect?

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "libtdsodbc.so", Server = "localhost", 
                 Database = "CBD", UID = "SA", PWD = "mypwd", 
                 Port = 1433, Trusted_Connection="True")
```